# Xcode - Setting accessibility identifier to UIDatePicker to automate it

Tags: accessibility, xcode9, appium-ios

I want to test my iOS app using Appium on Mac machine.

I have set the accessibility identifier attribute to all the controls in Xcode for the app.
However, I would like to get help in setting the accessibility for UIDatePickers as I am not able to get the accessibility identifier in appium inspecter.

I set the accessibilty identifiers for the rest controls by giving value to the field accessibility identifier in Interface Builder or either n code.

But in the case of UIDatePicker, I canntot see the section of accessibilityIDentifier to give the value. I tried giving it in User defined attribute section as well, but I didn't see the accessibity identifier when I checked in Appium inspecter

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi Divi, 
Have you found a solution ? (facing same issue here)

Answer (score -1):

There is no much need in adding accessibility identifier for UIDatePicker, until you can find it with IosClassChain strategy like `type = "XCUIElementTypePickerWheel"`

You can find the proper way of selecting values using [mobile: selectPickerWheelValue](http://appium.io/test/fixtures/sample.html#mobile-selectpickerwheelvalue) in Appium

```
//Java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("order", "next");
params.put("offset", 0.15);
params.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
js.executeScript("mobile: selectPickerWheelValue", params);
```